# OutOfMemoryException was unhandled Image.FromFile() in C#

Tags: c#

i got out of memory exception upon loading image from file.. i retrieve the file from database and the output file image can be viewed..

```
String temp = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop) + "/img.jpg";

using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(temp, FileMode.Create))
            {
                fs.Write(StudentImage(id), 0, StudentImage(id).Length);
                fParent.picAvatar.BackgroundImage = Image.FromFile(temp);
                //fParent.picAvatar.Image = Image.FromFile(temp2);
            }
private byte[] StudentImage(String _id)
    {
        try
        {
            String sqlCmd = String.Format("SELECT studpic FROM dbo.studentpic WHERE idnum = '{0}'", _id);
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(gVar._conString))
            {
                con.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlCmd, con);
                using (SqlDataReader r = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    r.Read();

                    byte[] imgData = (byte[])r["studpic"];
                    return imgData;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            return null;
        }
    }
```

did i miss any object that needs to close?

Comment: or maybe the data within the file is corrupted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You tend to get an OutOfMemory exception when an image cannot be read for a number of reasons.

In your case the issue is that you have not closed your file!  Also, you are calling the database twice.

I suggest the following code:

```
File.WriteAll(temp, StudentImage(id));
fParent.picAvatar.Image = Image.FromFile(temp);
```